# If I create webpages using html 5 elements, will I need equivalent html 4 webpages to support non html 5 browsers?

Tags: html

I would like to embrace html 5, if I use html 5 features, does that mean non-html 5 browsers won't be able to render properly?

Therefore, if I create webpages using html 5 elements, will I need to create equivalent html 4 webpages to support the non html 5 browsers?

Comment: Almost forgot (commenting because you already picked an answer), you should definitely take a look at the modernizr.js library.
It performs automatic feature detection in your browser (specific elements and css properties), and will gracefully handle this for older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes. In addition to the HTML elements, you'll need to make sure the script is compatible. Some browser versions are partially HTML 5 compatible like IE9.

You might find this link interesting in terms of HTML 5 browser support:

http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Although most browsers support most of the latest HTML5 features, you will **not** need equivilant html4 pages fr those browsers that do not support HTML5. You can use a **polyfill**. A polyfill is an extra script that adds support for something to a browseer that does not natively support it.

Here is a very good resource for polyfills:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Answer (score -1):

No. All current browsers support HTML5 elements.

Comment: This is wrong. It is a fact that the latest versions of most current browsers support it. But that still does not prevent a big amount of people from still using older versions of said browsers.

Comment: "Forrester says that nearly 75 percent of users in North America and 83 percent in Europe are running browsers that support a large segment of the HTML5 feature set" - [link](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/08/forrester-report-urges-html5-adoption-says-most-browsers-can-support-it/).  This means that around one quarter of people accessing my site with a non html 5 browser will not render the site properly?

Comment: @Kippie I spent so many years supporting IE6 etc. I don't care about not latest version of any web browser (And company I'm working for).

Comment: @Kippie Another thing is that updated to the latest browser version is standard right now, users don't need to do this by hand. Even Microsoft forced all Windows to upgrade IE to version 9.

Comment: @user1502048 Personally I test application only in Google Chrome. And checking on MDN if some browser's JS API I want to use is a standard or not.